# Apex trigger creating duplicate child records

Tags: apex, case, before-trigger

The goal of this case trigger is to parse out a CC List text string on the case object and insert each individual string as an email on the CC_List__c object. This is working, albeit a bit too well!

Unfortunately, each time the case is saved, the CC List field on the case is duplicating records on the CC_List__c object. My goal is to have the CC List field on the case object always 1 for 1 match the values listed in the related object's CC_List__c list.

```
trigger CCList on Case (after insert, before update, before delete) {
class CaseTriggerUtil {
    void handleCCFieldChangeEvent(Case [] argCases, Boolean argIsDelete) {
        Set<ID> lDeadParentIDSet = new Set<ID>();
        Set<String> lUniqueCCIDSet = new Set<String>();
        List<CC_List__c> lNewCCRecords = new List<CC_List__c>();

        for(Case lCase : argCases) {
            if(argIsDelete) {
                lDeadParentIDSet.add(lCase.id);
            }
            else {
                if(lCase.CC_List__c == null || lCase.CC_List__c.trim() == '') {
                    lDeadParentIDSet.add(lCase.id);
                    continue;
                }

                List<String> lCCValues = lCase.CC_List__c.trim().split(',');

                for(String lStrCC : lCCValues) {
                    String lStrChildRecUniqueID = lCase.id + '_' + lStrCC.trim();
                    lNewCCRecords.add(new CC_List__c(Related_Case__c=lCase.id, My_ID__c = lStrChildRecUniqueID, Email_Address__c = lStrCC.trim()));
                    lUniqueCCIDSet.add(lStrChildRecUniqueID);
                }
            }
        }

        if(!argIsDelete) {
            Database.insert(lNewCCRecords, false);
        }

        delete [SELECT id FROM CC_List__c WHERE Related_Case__c IN:lDeadParentIDSet OR (Related_Case__c IN:argCases AND My_ID__C NOT IN:lUniqueCCIDSet)];
    }
}

List<Case> lCases = (Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new);
new CaseTriggerUtil().handleCCFieldChangeEvent(lCases, Trigger.isDelete);}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you delete all child objs each trigger execution and rebuild them from `cc_list__c`. This is the easiest solution if it is not important to preserve the child createdDate or createdById

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. By wiping the CC List before I run the rest of my code and deleting the delete function, I achieve my desired results.

Final code:

```
trigger CCList on Case (after insert, after update, after delete) {

class CaseTriggerUtil {
    void handleCCFieldChangeEvent(Case [] argCases, Boolean argIsDelete) {
        Set<ID> lDeadParentIDSet = new Set<ID>();
        Set<String> lUniqueCCIDSet = new Set<String>();
        List<CC_List__c> lNewCCRecords = new List<CC_List__c>();

delete [SELECT id FROM CC_List__c WHERE Related_Case__c IN:argCases];

        for(Case lCase : argCases) {
            if(argIsDelete) {
                lDeadParentIDSet.add(lCase.id);
            }
            else {
                if(lCase.CC_List__c == null || lCase.CC_List__c.trim() == '') {
                    lDeadParentIDSet.add(lCase.id);
                    continue;
                }

                List<String> lCCValues = lCase.CC_List__c.trim().split(',');

                for(String lStrCC : lCCValues) {
                    String lStrChildRecUniqueID = lCase.id + '_' + lStrCC.trim();
                    lNewCCRecords.add(new CC_List__c(Related_Case__c=lCase.id, My_ID__c = lStrChildRecUniqueID, Email_Address__c = lStrCC.trim()));
                    lUniqueCCIDSet.add(lStrChildRecUniqueID);
                }
            }
        }

        if(!argIsDelete) {
            Database.insert(lNewCCRecords, false);
        }
    }
}

List<Case> lCases = (Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new);
new CaseTriggerUtil().handleCCFieldChangeEvent(lCases, Trigger.isDelete);}
```